# How to distinguish between two forms in class based View

Tags: python, django

I have two form from which i got file input in single view. So my aim is to seprate files from one form from files from another. I would like to access somehow form attributes, preferably form fields attributes and based on this to make some processing in post view. Like:

```
<form>
 <input type="file" id="test_file" name="file">
</form>

class UploadedFileForm(forms.ModelForm):
...

def post(self, request):
 form = UploadedFileForm(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
```

and here i want to check if the file source form. In my case if, for instance, file is from the field with id `test_file` then do some processing, or else do another one.

Currently i handle this situation having two different views one for each form, but want to combine it in one.